# connectedAndroidTest - Task has not declared any outputs

Tags: android, testing, gradle, android-studio

Sometimes my connectedAndroidTest doesn't actually execute any tests, even though the connected device seems to be found. I end up with a report like the following:

[image: Test Summary]

Doing `gradle --info connectedAndroidTest` I get:

```
Executing task ':app:connectedAndroidTest' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
```

I restarted the device one time and got my report. But that doesn't always help.

I'm using a (rooted) Samsung Tab 2, running Android 4.1.1. I'm using gradle/the latest Android Studio on a Mac with OS X 10.9.4. Ideas?

Comment: just wanna say I share your pain.. dealing with gradle android and unit tests :( Maybe you should show your build.gradle so others can have a clue. For me, build process doesn't even trigger connectedAndroidTest... every time I have to run the test and the call gradle clean build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Gradle test when all tests are UP-TO-DATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427020/how-to-run-gradle-test-when-all-tests-are-up-to-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need "--rerun-tasks" to force the tests to rerun when no code has changed.

More details and extensive discussion here: [How to run Gradle test when all tests are UP-TO-DATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427020/how-to-run-gradle-test-when-all-tests-are-up-to-date#29428063)

Comment: I didn't verify the answer. I've long moved on to other projects and don't really remember this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define your test package and Instrumentation test runner? In the example below I defined it inside the android section:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1"
    testApplicationId "com.example.tests"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
}
```