# Disable test cache when running through gradle

Tags: unit-testing, caching, gradle, gradlew

When I tried to run the same test once again:

```
$ ./gradlew -Dtest.single=KafkaStreamsTest streams:test

> Configure project :
Building project 'core' with Scala version 2.11.11


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

How do I disable the cache so that gradlew runs the whole test ?

Thanks

Comment: `--rerun-tasks` perhaps?

Comment: See the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428063/3256989

Answer (score 8):

This command would run the test (note cleanTest):

```
./gradlew cleanTest -Dtest.single=KafkaStreamsTest streams:test
```

Answer (score 3):

In Gradle 7.6 you can use option

```
gradle test --rerun
```

`--rerun` causes the task to be re-run even if up-to-date. Similar to `--rerun-tasks`, but only for a specific task.

Answer (score 3):

and for reference if you would like to run tests without skipping due to cache

```
gradle clean build --no-build-cache
```