# what's the gradle equivalent of sbt's "testQuick"

Tags: scala, testing, gradle, sbt

Scala's sbt has the option to run only tests that previously failed. Is there a gradle equivalent?

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#testQuick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gradle does this automatically with all update-to-date tests marked as such, based on code changes since latest test passing.

You can also force re-run of tests if need be: [How to run Gradle test when all tests are UP-TO-DATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427020/how-to-run-gradle-test-when-all-tests-are-up-to-date)