# Kotlin test not found, but only sometimes

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, junit5

Here is the test that I'd like to run:

```
@Test
fun testRequestFails() = runBlocking {
    assertFailsWith(ClientRequestException::class) {
        val result = httpClient.get<MyResponse>("$baseUrl/some/req/that/should/fail") {
            header(API_KEY_HEADER, testApiKey)
        }
    }
}
```

`httpClient.get` is a `suspend fun`.  When I try to run this with `./gradlew test` or IDEA, **the test is silently skipped**!  When I try to run this one specifically in IDEA, it says "No tests found for given includes."

However! I can make it findable and runnable by either assigning the result of `assertFailsWith` to a variable, or by adding `assertEquals(1,1)` to the end of the test.

I'm probably doing something wrong with coroutines, but in my head, if I write a test wrong, it should *fail*, not *disappear*

***It's deeply troubling that a test can disappear without warning!***

1. Is there a way to ensure the test is discoverable, without doing a useless variable assignment or a useless assert?
2. Is there a way to make giant alarm bells go off if a test fails to get discovered?

Snippets from build.gradle.kts:

```
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0")

    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-mock-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktorVersion")
}
```

Comment: What’s the name of your test class? Test discovery does filtering with regard to class names by default

Comment: Apart from that I recommend you give a full reproducible example with build files and everything.

Comment: It's not the test or class names, since the tests work when I only change the *contents* of the methods.
You're right that I should package this into a gist or something, maybe it should be a bug report.

Comment: Gradle will skip any task that hasn't changed https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484259/4161471 - and that's okay. Personally I prefer locally only running changed tests, and on CI/CD it will re-run all tests.